# discord.py json warn command logging warns

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a warn command using a json file but I keep getting this traceback.
I'm not sure what part was "never awaited" and I'm not sure which part is getting the error. Please help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 261, in <module>
    async def warn(ctx,member:discord.Member,*reason:str):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 289, in decorator
    result = hybrid_command(name=name, *args, with_app_command=with_app_command, **kwargs)(func)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/hybrid.py", line 888, in decorator
    return HybridCommand(func, name=name, with_app_command=with_app_command, **attrs)  # type: ignore  # ???
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/hybrid.py", line 509, in __init__
    HybridAppCommand(self) if self.with_app_command else None
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/hybrid.py", line 306, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 677, in __init__
    self._params: Dict[str, CommandParameter] = _extract_parameters_from_callback(callback, callback.__globals__)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 393, in _extract_parameters_from_callback
    param = annotation_to_parameter(resolved, parameter)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/app_commands/transformers.py", line 863, in annotation_to_parameter
    raise TypeError(f'unsupported parameter kind in callback: {parameter.kind!s}')
TypeError: unsupported parameter kind in callback: VAR_POSITIONAL
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
```

Here's my code

```
@client.hybrid_command(name = "warn", with_app_command=True, description="Warn a user")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,member:discord.Member,*reason:str):
    author = ctx.author
    if not reason:
        await ctx.send("Please provide a reason")
        return
        reason = ' '.join(reason)
        await ctx.send(f'**{member.mention} has been warned by {author.name}.**')
        await member.send(f'You have been warned in **{ctx.guild.name}** by **{author.name}**.')
        for current_user in report['users']:
            if current_user['name'] == member.name:
                current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
                break
    else:
        report['users'].append({
           'name':member.name,
           'reasons': [reason,]
        })
        with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
            json.dump(report,f) 
            
@client.hybrid_command(name = "warnings", with_app_command=True, description="View the warnings of a user", aliases=["punishments", "warns"])
async def warnings(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    for current_user in report['users']:
        if member.name == current_user['name']:
            await ctx.send(f"**{member.name} has been reported {len(current_user['reasons'])} times : {','.join(current_user['reasons'])}**")
            break
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"**{member.name} has never been warned**")
```

Comment: Try changing `async def warn(ctx,member:discord.Member,*reason:str):` to `async def warn(ctx, member:discord.Member, reason:str):`. This will cause the command to only accept a single string as the reason argument, rather than a variable number of arguments. You can then handle the multiple arguments in your command implementation if necessary.

Comment: @A-poc after doing that it ran, but when trying to do the command it gave me no traceback all it said in the console was 'users'